# Inline If failing to update variable value

Tags: unity, c#

So, I have a toggle button to change a bool value, in this script 't1Bool'. The toggle button is working because when I use a Debug.log I can see the value changing from true o false when I press the button. When using the Debug.log with the variable turbina1 the value is always zero. I already checked the if condition syntax and don't know why this value is not being updated.

```
using System;
using UnityEngine;
namespace Assets.Code.PowerPlants
{
    public class HydroElectric
    {
        public bool t1Bool;
        public bool t2Bool;
        public bool t3Bool;

        int turbina1;
        int turbina2;
        int turbina3;

        public float prod;

        public HydroElectric ()
        {   
         t1Bool = true;
         t2Bool = true;
         t3Bool = false;
         prod = 0f; 
        }

        public float HydroControlPanel ()
        {
            turbina1 = t1Bool ? 2 : 0;
            turbina2 = t2Bool ? 3 : 0;
            turbina3 = t3Bool ? 1 : 0;

            prod = turbina1 + turbina2 + turbina3;
            Debug.Log (turbina1);
            return prod;
        }
    }
}
```

This is the code for the button:

```
public void ShowIt()
{
            ec.t1Bool = GUI.Toggle (new Rect (25, 55, 100, 50), ec.t1Bool, "Turbina 2 MW");

            ec.t2Bool = GUI.Toggle (new Rect (25, 95, 100, 50), ec.t2Bool, "Turbina 3 MW");

            ec.t3Bool = GUI.Toggle (new Rect (25, 135, 100, 50), ec.t3Bool, "Turbina 1 MW");

            GUI.Box (new Rect (Screen.width - 100, 60, 80, 25), ec.prod.ToString ());      // PRODUCED ENERGY

        }
```

This is where the object instance is created (it is in the same script as the button):

```
public class PlayState : IStateBase
    {
        private StateManager manager;
        private HydroElectric ec;
        public PlayState (StateManager managerRef)
        {
            manager = managerRef;
            Debug.Log ("Constructing PlayState");
            ec = new HydroElectric();
        }
```

Any hint?

Comment: `turbina1` is marked as static, are you sure you meant for it to be static?

Comment: it seems not, I've already removed it but the problem persists.

Comment: The problem is with only turbina1 or with all three?

Comment: Can we see the code for the button?

Comment: The problem is with all three. I've just added the code for the button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In last line, it should be ec.HydroControlPanel().ToString() instead of ec.prod.ToString() in ShowIt method

Comment: To explain: the button updated the internal on/off state, but `HydroControlPanel()` which calculates the total output based on that internal on/off state is never called, thus `prod` is never updated.

Comment: @Draco18s thanx man, m on cell phone. Thanx for explaining. And u r welcome ClaudioA :)

Comment: @HamzaHasan No problem.  I know the joys (read "troubles") of trying to type anything longer than four words on a mobile device (mine has a quirk dating back a few months where the learned dictionary words got completely wiped, along with a number of *real* words, like "do."  I cannot type "do" on my tablet except through painstaking manuality, if I forget I get "so" "Co" "dip" "drop" or something else).

Comment: @Draco18s A big LOL :D

Comment: @HamzaHasan Its also conveniently stopped learning new words 9.9 Right pain in the arse.  Used to take it about six to ten usages of a word or proper noun for me to be able to use it in swipe-typing ("continuous input") but since the "update" I haven't seen it learn a single new word.

Comment: @Draco18s Can you listen my double pain?? I have Windows Phone :D

Comment: @HamzaHasan you poor, poor bastard. I can at least understand my (dumb, flip) phone taking years to learn the word "cashew" (man, I loved that phone--the Samsung U-550--I had it for *five years* before I accidentally ran it through the wash; my replacement Convoy 3 hasn't quite been as good) but my android tablet?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33539/discussion-between-hamza-hasan-and-draco18s).